# Multitrack-Audio with Java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I plan to have ~100 synchronized audio tracks playing with live controllable volume per track. The audio comes from `wav` files.

Are there any libraries / best practices to achieve this in Java?

Comment: You're wanting to use Java as the environment for playing the audio in real time?

Comment: Yes, I've got a Java Application with the Processing library and like to add some audio.

Comment: As much as I'm a fan of Java, this probably isn't the best approach for it; Java doesn't have real-time guarantees, and you never know when (for example) you'll end up with a stutter because of garbage collection or hot-spot recompiling.

Comment: There's the `Java Sound API`, and also I'm not doing complex synthesis, but only `wav` playback. I wouldn't mind for one or the other stutter, it's only a prototype application.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at Praxis and JAudioLibs. Neil Smith knows his stuff.

I've gotten maybe 30-50 wavs playing at once, and my library is certainly not the most efficient. And I wasn't changing volumes or pans for those wav files. If some of those sounds of yours are short enough to be stored in memory (e.g., a bank of sound effects) then you have a bit more chance of success in having so many tracks. I've gotten 100 short clips running at once (using a custom made clip, but again, no volume or panning added except the trigger values).

There's a good article on the real-time issues with Java. The issues are real but not insurmountable. Java is pretty low-level and fast, if you stick with the lowest level tools provided by javax.audio.sampled library, and don't mind a bit of latency.

http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx?c=icmc;idno=bbp2372.2007.131

Controlling volume real-time is tough, as it requires either a very small buffer or a means of going in and doing per-frame calculations, or else risk getting effects like zippering or clicks. I had some success with real-time volume changing when I time-stamped mouse-motion-listener output and calculated the intermediate volumes. But I haven't tried applying that to more than one channel at a time. (It was a virtual Theremin project).

However, there might be a way to pre-build a selection of envelopes that would be quite efficient, and control volume via selecting from a menu of these envelopes. Hmmmm.

It's a challenging problem, and I don't know if even my DAW (Cakewalk Sonar, written in some flavor of C) would be able to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I've already stumbled across JAudioLibs earlier and will try it out. Maybe I can reduce the necessary simultaneous audio tracks. Actually for most cases, most of these tracks have volume 0, but I fear not loading them until they are needed would introduce massive crackling. I want to do some blending accross the tracks, and thus they alwas need to be synchronized and ready to aurally appear. I'm aware that I won't be able to compete with the performance of commercial DAWs, so maybe I just check first if my idea would be feasible in a DAW (FL Studio in my case).

Comment: Synchronizing should be ok if wavs themselves all really do share a common 0th frame. You can load them all into the mixer, ready to go, so that each file is read once with each iteration of the mixer, and turn the mixer on as a single act. (I'm using term "mixer" in a music studio sense, not the Java definition.) Also one can read and discard data from tracks with 0 volume. Sometimes crackle comes from volume overflow: easy to do when adding so many tracks together. If this is long-playing, might be too much to put all in memory as "clip" type data. Am curious what you come up with.